# How to get corresponding value from query data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am have MSSQL tables as below

```
Names
 sno     username    firstname
   1      jim         sam
   2      raj         ravi
   3      lion        king

Marks
 sno     from        given  
   1      raj         jim
   2      raj         lion
   3      lion        raj
   4      lion        jim
```

Now I wanted to display my table as shown below:

```
Select  [from],
        [given]
  From  Marks
  Where [from] = 'raj'
```

Output Table:

```
from     given     firstname  
 raj      jim       sam
 raj      lion      king
```

How can I acheve it I am unable to figure it out?

Comment: So what's the common element between these two tables? Is it that the Names.[username] field has the same value as the Marks.[given] field? I gather it's not the [sno] field because there's no match for raj/lion/king with the same sno.

Comment: your schema is no good, what are you trying to compare is nonsensical.

Comment: Ideally the table would use a common identifier for the purposes of the join. So, for Names table, have a NamesID and set it the primary key. Then, for the Marks table, have a MarksID, and set it the primary key. Then, if the Marks table has a reference to a Name (a Foreign Key from the Names table), then include a NamesID field in it, and have the NamesID value from the Names table. Then, do the join with a statement such as `WHERE Marks.NameID = Names.NameID`.

Comment: I am trying to get the firstname of the user

Comment: Nooooooooo! You have a column named FROM? Have you gone mad sir?

Comment: I'm telling you right now OP this **WILL** cause you problems don't use reserved names for you columns it's a **BAD** idea.

Comment: ok sure I will follow all your suggestions. I am just learning MSSQL.  Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select marks.from, marks.given, names.fistname
  from marks
  join names
    on marks.given = names.username
 where marks.from = 'raj'
```

Comment: @user2787300 change your column names!

Comment: @Zane Sure I have followed your suggestions and changed my column names. Thank you so much.